# ICN 3.0.3 - Change mimetype of files when we double click and download them or right click and download

Tags: ibm-content-navigator

In the search result when we double click on the files to open/download them, I want to change the mime type of such files.
Like when I open a file named abc.trns I want to change it's extension to PDF - abc.pdf. The new mime type value is already displayed in a column from where I have to fetch that value (new mimetype value is present in doc property).

Please help in how this can be achieved, I'm very new in ICN plugin development.
If anyone has already developed such plugin please share the source code for reference.

Repository - CMOD 9.5
ICN - version 3.0.3

Answer (score 0):

the plugin development examples are present in  the redbook. Please refer those  example for the on-click event for download.

Once you get that setup - have the event handler read the metadata  (from where you get the extension ) and pass it on to function to convert the data stream  into specific format.

Please note the above conversion will require extra  jar and dependencies on the  type of document you want to convert. Here you have to take into consideration all the extension which comes in from that field.

hope this  helps :)